# How to do unit testing for session timeout in VB?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, web-config, session-state, session-timeout

I am working on a VB project where I had to increase the session timeout of the page to 9 hours. I achieved it by adding `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="540"></sessionState>` in the `web.config` file

Now I have to write the unit testing for the same in VB. I have not written any unit test ever before. I know unit testing can be done on individual unit or group of interrelated units of the software. Is there a way to unit test session timeout? There is no login involved here.

Please give some reference. Some blog or existing question(s).
I am new to both VB and unit testing.

Comment: If the only change is adding that time-out value to `web.config` (and it doesn't involve any code that was previously written on your end), then it's not something that's suitable for unit testing.  Unit tests should be used to verify that externally-accessible entry points in your code function as designed.  They should not verify that the language or framework functions as designed.

Comment: I was thinking the same but the task assigned to me was titled "Development and unit testing". Never mind I confirmed with the team. No need for test cases as there are no logical code changes. Thanks for responding :)